# When user logged in my side bar menus are not showing

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular Application, When user logged in sidebar menus are not showing. It's show the api data in backend for side menu is empty in browser. Here's my **side-bar.component.ts**

```
         export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit,OnChanges {
        
          private userName: string;
          private users: any[];
          public menuItemList = [];
        
          menuItems: any = [];
          backArrow = faArrowLeft;
          isSideMenuActive: boolean;
          version: string;
          mainItemURL: string;
          subItemURL: string;
          roleName: string;
          menuDataSet: any;
          
        
          arrowDown = faChevronCircleDown;
          arrowUp = faChevronCircleUp;
        
          constructor(
            private initialService: InitialService,
            private dataService: HttpService,
            private endPoints: InitialService,
            private headerService: HeaderService,
            private modalService: NgbModal,
            private router: Router,
            private httpClient: HttpClient,
            private auth: AuthService
            ) {
            this.headerService.isSideBarActive.subscribe(isActive => {
              this.isSideMenuActive = isActive;
            });
            this.version = this.initialService.getVersion();
          }
          ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
            if (changes.menuDataSet) {
              console.log('change');
              this.roleName = localStorage.getItem('roleName');
              this.getRoles();
            }
          }
          ngOnDestroy(): void {
            throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
          }
          
          ngAfterViewInit(): void {
            this.roleName = localStorage.getItem('roleName');
            this.getRoles();
          }
        
          ngOnInit() {
            this.userName = localStorage.getItem('user');
            this.roleName = localStorage.getItem('roleName');
            // this.getRoles();
            // this.getUsers();
            this.auth.getMenus().subscribe((res: any)=>{
              console.log(res);
              this.menuItems = res
              res.forEach(e => {
            
              });
            })
          }
        
          getRoles() {
            this.getMenu();
            
          }
    
     onMainItemSelected(item) {
        this.subItemURL = '';
        if (item != '#') {
          this.mainItemURL = item;
        }
      }
      onSubItemSelected(item) {
        this.mainItemURL = '';
        if (item != '#') {
          this.subItemURL = item;
        }
      }
    
      toggleSideBar() {
        this.headerService.toggleSideBar();
      }
    
      showProgress(item) {
        switch (item) {
          default:
            return item;
        }
      }
    
      openVersionModel() {
        const modal = this.modalService.open(VersionComponent, { size: 'lg', scrollable: true});
        modal.componentInstance.title = "Locations";
      }
    
      public getMenu(){
        const details = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('details'));
        console.log("details");
        console.log(details);
        const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + details);
        const headers = { headers: header };
        console.log('responseOK');
        this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:85/api/menus/', headers).subscribe(data => {
          this.menuDataSet = data;
          console.log(this.menuDataSet);
        });
      }

**Api Menu items**

[
    {
        "item": "Site Dashboard",
        "url": "/overview",
        "subMenus": []
    },
    {
        "item": "Electrical - HT",
        "url": "/ht-site-electrical",
        "subMenus": []
    },
    {
        "item": "Electrical - LT",
        "url": "/site-electrical",
        "subMenus": []
    },
    {
        "item": "Water",
        "url": "/site-water",
        "subMenus": []
    },
    {
        "item": "Alerts",
        "url": "/alerts",
        "subMenus": []
    },
    {
        "item": "Configuration",
        "url": "/configurations",
        "subMenus": []
    },
    {
        "item": "User Management",
        "url": "/user-managment",
        "subMenus": []
    }
]
```

This is what showing when user logged in. It's initialize in ngOninit and i need to know how to fix this.

```
{
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
title: "One or more validation errors occurred.",
status: 400,
traceId: "|c1254bf8-422709e09132ae40.",
errors: {
authorization: [
"The authorization field is required."
]
}
}
```

[Localhost:4200/api/users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNzcM.png)

*side-bar.component.html*

```
<div class="h-100 w-100 position-relative">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100px; display: flex;">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 mt-2 d-xl-none d-lg-none" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100;">
      <fa-icon class="browse fa-lg cursor-pointer" [icon]="backArrow"  (click)="toggleSideBar()"></fa-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 pl-5 pr-5 pt-3 text-center">
      <img src="/assets/img/logo.png"  class="img-fluid w-75" alt="Logo">
      <p class="text-center">
        <small>Azbil Singapore</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="height: calc(100vh - 140px); overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 pl-0 pr-0">
      <ul class="menu top-level" *ngIf="menuDataSet && menuDataSet.length > 0">
        <li *ngFor="let item of menuDataSet">
          <span class="pl-3 pt-2 pr-3 pb-2 d-block menu-item" (click)="onMainItemSelected(item.url)" [ngClass]="[item.subMenus.length != 0 ? 'inactive' : '', mainItemURL == item.url ? 'active': '']" [routerLink]="item.url == '#' ? [] : [item.url]" [innerHtml]="showProgress(item.item)"></span>
          <ul *ngIf="item.subMenus.length > 0">
            <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.subMenus">
              <span class="pl-5 pt-2 pr-3 pb-2 d-block menu-item sub-menu-item" (click)="onSubItemSelected(subItem.url)" [ngClass]="{'active': subItemURL == subItem.url}" [routerLink]="subItem.url" [innerHtml]="showProgress(subItem.item)"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <p class="text-center footer-version" (click)="openVersionModel()">Version {{version}}</p>
</div>
```

[before logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9oh0.png)[after logging and side bar(Menus disappears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irDdf.png)

**Angular version** : 8
**Node version** : 15.2

Comment: can u create issue in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qjjpzp

Comment: I have very big project and lot of components need to import.

Comment: Issue is when user logged in side bar items not showing!

Comment: authorization: [
"The authorization field is required."
]
 Authorization header should be implement in request header. that will solve the problem. is it working on Postman ?

Comment: Yes. You can see when scroll down, I attached the api result in postman

Comment: would you able to show me as a instance how to implement the header. I'm bit comfused

Comment: 1. console.log(details);
        const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + details);
2. console.log(this.menuDataSet); 

what is the result in this console ?

And can u check in request header "Authorization"?  what value is sent?

Comment: getMenus(){
  const details  = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + details);
  const headers = { headers: header };
  return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:85/api/menus', headers);
}

Comment: problem is when user logged side menu item in not showing!

Comment: This is what showing .      {
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
title: "One or more validation errors occurred.",
status: 400,
traceId: "|c1254bf8-422709e09132ae40.",
errors: {
authorization: [
"The authorization field is required."
]
}
}

Comment: in which console it is showing ? { type: "tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1", title: "One or more validation errors occurred.", status: 400, traceId: "|c1254bf8-422709e09132ae40.", errors: { authorization: [ "The authorization field is required." ] } }

Comment: in localhosht api url

Comment: I have attached image above please check it!

Comment: whats the console where `getMenu()` is called `console.log("details");`

try to deploy it in stackblitz so we can get it

Comment: i think  in `getMenu()`  the auth code which you are binding is not passing through.

Comment: I have very large application so it's hard to deploy in the stackblitz.

Comment: I will attach my component.html so you can guess that

Comment: It seems backend issue. 500 status code. and can u capture full image of Header one?

Comment: @rajhim please check the attached images